# Why do I have to use HubContext to send complex object back to clients?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I am getting started with SignalR and would like to know why this works:

```
public interface IPadHubClient
{
    void AddEvent(EntityEvent entityEvent);    
}


public class PadHub : Hub<IPadHubClient>
{        
    public void AddEvent(EntityEvent entityEvent)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PadHub>();
        context.Clients.All.AddEvent(entityEvent);
    }    
}
```

while this doesn't:

```
public class PadHub : Hub<IPadHubClient>
{        
    public void AddEvent(EntityEvent entityEvent)
    {
        Clients.All.AddEvent(entityEvent);
    }    
}
```

As you can see, on my hub I try to pass a complex object `EntityEvent` which was received from one client to all other clients. `EntityEvent` is a plain object containing a number of simple properties. Calling the method on the hub works in both cases: If I change the client's method signature to a string parameter and pass the `Id` of the `entityEvent` parameter on the hub, I get the correct Id. So obviously, passing the complex object from the client to the hub works in both cases.

However, the handler method on the client(s) are not called in the second case. In the first case, the complex object is received by the clients correctly.

I can provide more details, if needed, though I suspect it is not a bug, but by design...?

**So: What is the difference between calling `Clients.All.Something(ComplexType parameter)` and `context.Clients.All.Something(ComplexType parameter)`? Why does my example work with the context but not the hub?**